# STL ignores cropping in objects

Tags: export

is there anyone who can help with the following: a cropped object can be seen in both object-mode and in edit-mode, but the changes are not included in the STL file.
I have used apply every time a crop has been performed and the model is non-manifold

Comment: How exactly have you "cropped" the object and would you mind sharing at least one or two screenshots to show what you have done? And what do you mean the object is non-manifold, in which way? Non-manifold geometry is something that cannot exist in the real world and is therefore not desired if you want to e.g. 3D print it. You need manifold geometry.

Comment: Please illustrate, and tell us how you cropped the object.

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for your feedback. It should have said manifold (waterproof). I became a member yesterday and have already found a solution to my problem by reading the various questions, a problem that I have otherwise spent months solving namely
solution: to finish by adding triangulate modifier. I am really impressed with the help and opportunities in this community